# Is there a Unicode-compatible alternative to PGN?

Tags: pgn

One of the [problems with PGN](https://zuttobenkyou.wordpress.com/2012/01/27/problems-with-the-portable-game-notation-pgn-standard/) is that it requires ASCII, while names of players often contain non-ASCII characters. (And of course, many names are not written in the Latin alphabet ...)

The background to this question is the rendering of non-ASCII characters in Arena 3.5.1 (on Windows 7), as in the image below. The names for white and black are `Mittelsträß, Jürg` and `王, 玥`, respectively. Arena reads the UTF-8-encoded file as if it were encoded as [Windows Codepage 1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252). Editors such as Notepad++, SublimeText and JEdit identify the file as UTF-8 (which is the default encoding of all my plain text files, anyway).

[image]

Here's an example PGN for testing:

```
[Event "Office Armageddon"]
[Site "Böblingen GER"]
[Date "??.??.??"]
[Round "?"]
[White "Mittelsträß, Jürg"]
[Black "王, 玥"]
[Result "*"]
[SetUp "1"]
[Mode "OTB"]
[Termination "unterminated"]

1. d2-d4 d7-d5 2. e2-e3 c7-c5 3. Bf1-b5+ Bc8-d7 4. a2-a4 Ng8-f6 5. d4xc5 e7-e5 6. b2-b4 Nb8-c6 7. Ng1-f3 Qd8-c7 8. Nb1-c3 a7-a6 9.  *
```

([SCID](http://scidvspc.sourceforge.net/doc/Encoding.htm) assumes a system encoding if a PGN is encoded in UTF-8 without a byte order mark (BOM), but the BOM makes no difference in Areana 3.5.1.)

So I'd like to know if there is a **Unicode-compatible alternative (ideally UTF-8)** that is supported by some chess programs. (If not, PGN needs an overhaul.)

Answer (score 2):

https://sourceforge.net/p/pgn4web/wiki/PGN_Support/

if you read that, you will notice:

[image: Screenshot]
 `in order for pgn4web to display those characters correctly, the PGN file should be saved in unicode UTF-8 format.`

you *can* save PGN as UTF-8... Just open `notepad > Save As... > Encoding` and select `UTF-8`. and you can then add the appropriate player names! I've tested this, and it works with Arena Chess and a few others...

Hope this solves your problem. ~CSS

Comment: I'm surprised that this is supposed to work in Arena. UTF-8 is the default encoding for all my plain text files, including PGN. When a PG file contains an `ü` Arena renders it as `Ã¼` (regardless whether I save the file as "UTF-8" or "UTF-8 without BOM"). Which Arena version are you using?

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe Arena 3.7.1 Alpha

Comment: I'll update my own version of Arena (3.0 Build 2542) in the next few days and test my UTF-8 encoded PGN again.

Comment: I now have Arena 3.5.1 build 2861 (20/12/2015), on Windows 7 (32 bits), and `ü` is still rendered as `Ã¼`.

Comment: I have updated my question with a screenshot of how Arena 3.5.1 build 2861 displays non-ASCII characters. It clearly treats my UTF-8 file as Windows Codepage 1252.

Comment: So, yes, [pgn4web games viewer](http://pgn4web.casaschi.net/viewer.php) supports UTF-8 and even supports Chinese characters. Thanks.

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of Arena with my example PGN rendering correctly?

Answer (score 2):

PGN databases created by ChessBase programs are encoded as UTF-8 by default, too.

Comment: Do you have an example of a UTF-8 encoded PGN file that uses non-ASCII characters? As long as you use only ASCII in such files, the UTF-8 encoding is irrelevant, as far as I know.

Comment: https://ingram-braun.net/public/programming/web/testpages/chess-game-viewer/replay/

Comment: Yes, I created a test file for pgn viewers embedded in web pages with German special characters. The above website (sorry, hit <ENTER> to early) shows the results. And I have no problems to type non-Latin characters in CB 14.